# Is everyone dream a correct sentence?

Tags: pronouns, singular-vs-plural

I just wanted to know that can I use verb + 's' with "Everyone".

Comment: You should check out [ell.se]. Everyone dreams of a site like that.

Comment: You can say "Everyone dream!" if you are issuing a command, but it would be a particularly strange command.

Answer (score 3):

Usually everyone is used on the third person of the singular (like 'she', 'he', 'it') so you can say:

"Everyone dreams" because it works as one person.

Answer (score 0):

With words like 'everyone', 'everything' and 'everywhere' we use singular verb.

So it should be **everyone dreams** as in J.R's comment:

> You should check out English Language Learners. **Everyone dreams** of a site like that.

Reference: [cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/everyone-everybody-everything-everywhere)